# Tire (ruby on rails) is adding my search parms as the index, not the query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using elasticsearch for syslog indexing, and would like to query elasticsearch from a rails app, so I'm trying to use tire.

Here are the results if I search for asa from my search box.

```
[REQUEST FAILED] curl -X GET 'http://localhost:9200/asa/_search?pretty' -d '{}'
```

notice the asa is in the index spot, if I change this from asa to _all, I get a search.

On index.html.erb I have this search box

```
<%= form_tag 'csdashboard', :method => :get do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :query, params[:query] %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Search logs..', name: nil %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller.

```
class CsdashboardController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if params[:query].present?
      @esearch = Tire.search(params[:query])
      render 'layouts/search'
    else
      render 'layouts/index'
    end
  end
end
```

Here is my search.html.erb

```
  <%= @esearch.results.to_json do %>
  <% end %>
```

Comment: What do your routes look like? (Share the relevant parts of routes.rb or the output of `rake routes`)

Comment: You might try `_search?query=pretty`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking such questions usually results in answers like: RTFM!

If you look at the documentation of tire (retire nowadays), there is the following example:

```
s = Tire.search 'articles' do
  query do
    string 'title:T*'
  end

  filter :terms, :tags => ['ruby']

  sort { by :title, 'desc' }

  facet 'global-tags', :global => true do
    terms :tags
  end

  facet 'current-tags' do
    terms :tags
  end
end
```

Do you notice anything? Correct, the argument passed to `search` is the index name. The code you provided does exactly that, it uses the parameter to set the index name.

Comment: Well I did RTFM, but not well enough I guess. Thanks, I think I'm on the right track.